# Обыкновенный цикл for

Tags: соревнование

Пришло время <s>офигительных</s> классического гольфа!

Итак, у нас есть функция на C# или аналогичном языке:

```
void Print(int min, int max)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    checked // бросаем исключение при переполнении
    {
        for (int i = min /*----------------*/)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Необходимо заменить комментарий `/*----------------*/` на однострочный код так, чтобы в результате выполнения этой функции на консоль выдавались все числа от `min` до `max` включительно. Больше ничего менять нельзя!

Выигрывает самое короткое решение по количеству *добавленных* символов. Разрешается использовать не только C#, но в языке должен присутствовать цикл `for` (в этом случае заменить код на такой же по смыслу). Функция должна отработать без ошибок.

Да, решения, основанные на переполнениях запрещены (при помощи `checked`), чтобы не было большой разницы между C# и C++.

Обратите внимание на особые случаи наподобие `min == int.Min`, `max == int.Max`, `min == max` и тому подобные. Можно считать, что `min <= max` при вызове.

---

## Финальный результат:

Решения @kmv, @pavel и @Zealint правильные, и реализуют по сути одну идею. Минимальный размер 17 символов.

Второе решение @kmv длиннее (около 50 символов), но с совершенно сумасшедшей (в положительном смысле) идеей.

Отличное нестандартное первое решения @kodv заняло 38 символов, второе решение того же автора аналогично решению @Qwertiy, минимум 30 символов.

Ещё одно решение @Qwertiy <s>более традиционное</s> тоже необычное, на текущий момент 26 символов.

Решения остальные участников пока, кажется, не подходят к условию.

---

К сожалению, из-за недостаточно однозначной формулировки условия решение @jfs на Питоне вызвало дискуссию, и в конечном итоге было снято автором. Ошибка в условии полностью на моей совести, приношу свои извинения.

Comment: а порядок выдачи чисел важен?

Comment: @Grundy Да важен, в условиях: "все числа от `min` до `max` включительно"

Comment: @Cerbo, эту строчку можно читать и как все числа _в интервале_ от min до max включительно. То есть не обязательно вывод должен быть таким: `min, min+1...,max-1,max`

Comment: @Grundy Таких тонкостей не указано, поэтому думаю следует понимать как написано. Однако, в своем ответе вы можете слегка перегнуть в эту сторону, если покажете что-то интересное.

Comment: @Cerbo если понимать как написано, то, например, `1 5 2 4 3` это вполне себе "все числа от 1 до 5 включительно". Ну... **целые**, конечно (но это уже следует из кода, `i` типа `int`). Нужно уточнение, либо "в порядке возрастания", либо "в любом порядке".

Comment: Жаль, что функциональные языки особо не применишь, что-нибудь типа `for i in min .. max -> printfn "%d" i` -- вообще читерство :)

Comment: Было бы здорово подобные конкурсы делать так, чтобы ответы участников появлялись все и с разу в обозначенное время. Тогда решения будут действительно самостоятельными.

Comment: @Zealint, а какая разница? если на основе одного ответа получился другой хороший - это тоже хорошо

Comment: Ох. Раз я этого явно не потребовал до первого ответа, будем считать, что неважен. Но повторения я бы всё же исключил.

Comment: @kmv: Ага, именно поэтому я специально потребовал семантику `for`. :)

Comment: @Zealint: Надо подумать, как такое можно организовать технически. Можно, например, запретить публикацию ответа, повторяющего идею уже существующего ответа. (Даже если ответ написан независимо.)

Comment: Запрещать нельзя, потому что заставляет постоянно смотреть сюда и отвлекаться от придумывания. Лучше как-то обозначить просто точное время (и часовой пояс), когда можно публиковать. Во-первых, не будет нечестности в том, что разные участники в разное время видят новость, во-вторых, не будет подсматривания (и соблазна к нему).

Comment: @Zealint, чем плохо подсматривание? :)

Comment: @Grundy, идеологически есть причины: (1) в гольфе каждый бьёт по своему мячу, а не по чужому, (2) при подсматривании не формируется навык самостоятельного мышления, и можно просто сидеть на выжидательной тактике. Придумать комбинированный ответ можно и после конкурса. Плохо ещё и то, что начало конкурса у всех разное получается. Кто-то ещё с работы не пришёл и увидит новость только ночью... а тут уже куча решений.

Comment: можно Leaderboard добавить? См. [code snippet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65020/1004)

Comment: @jfs: Ого, круто :) Для этого нужен header специального вида в каждом ответе?

Comment: @VladD: да, если человек хочет свой ответ в Leaderboard добавить, то `## Language Name, N bytes` в ответ добавить нужно (это соответствует распространённой практике для подобной инфы—для людей удобно сканировать ответы, которых десятки может быть). Для текущего вопроса, я бы руками ответы поправил. Возможно скрипт подкрутить, чтобы слова "символ", "байт" на русском понимал, если необходимо (не вижу надо это или нет).

Comment: @jfs: Спасибо, будет взято на вооружение.

Comment: @kmv: на луа `for i=min,max do print(i) end`. Именно читерство! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
for (int i=min,d=~i&1;(i^d)&1; i+=i<max, d^=1)
```

длинно, но пока первое что пришло в голову :)

посмотрел ответ @kmv

```
for (int i = min,d=1;d;i+=d=i<max)
```

уже похоже на что-то :)

C++, 17 символов.

Вариант для извращенцев, но может кто-то сумеет оформить в более компактный.

```
for (int i=min;;i<max?i++:(exit(0),0))
```

Comment: вот это ты захардкодил ;)

Comment: Это C++? Если да, указывайте. И можно ещё количество символов, а? Гольф всё-таки.

Comment: Второй вариант для шарпа будет выглядеть как-то так: `for (int i = min,d=1;d!=0;i+=d=i<max?1:0)`

Comment: alexolut  != замените на > и да. Но по сути такое же у @kmv в последнем ответе.

Comment: На первый вариант (с `~i&1`) смотреть? Он что-то кажется подозрительным.

Comment: @VladD посмотрите, он длинее но просто как идею.

Comment: А, `d` смотрит на чётность? Ага, понял идею.

Comment: 1. `?1:` => `||`? 2. Хочется как-то реорганизовать условный оператор, чтобы exit обходился без скобок. Можно поменять ветви местами - тогда скобки не понядобятся, но `<` превратится в `>=` - в итоге тот же 1 символ. PS: Экспериментально не проверял, но должно получиться.

Answer (score 14):

C#, 23 символа без учета пробелов, будет работать и на C/C++/Java.

```
for (int i = min, j = 1; j > 0; i += (j = i < max ? 1 : 0))
```

```
for (int i = min, j = 1; j > 0; i += j = i < max ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Скобки можно убрать, будет 23 символа

Comment: На плюсах `? 1 : 0` можно убрать. Но в шарпе и джаве - нет.

Answer (score 7):

Для C++ нужно вставить такой код
    `,min=1;min;min=(i<max),i+=min` (начинается с запятой, это не опечатка).

То есть у меня цикл выглядит так:

```
void Print(int min, int max) {
  for (int i = min,min=1;min;min=(i<max),i+=min)
    fprintf (stderr, "%i ", i);
  }
```

29 знаков добавлено, и я принципиально не хочу добавлять новую переменную, уменьшая размер.

Comment: стоит добавить весь код в сборе

Comment: можно по идее выкинуть внутренние скобки

Comment: А вы таки добавили новую переменную. `min` внутри цикла — новая переменная.

Comment: Тут всё дело вот в чём: я нашёл идею и показал её, но другие участники уже придумали до этого, как сделать короче. Поэтому не вижу смысла дорабатывать. Нужно что-то другое придумывать. Да, Стандарт языка я в этом месте плохо знаю...

Comment: В любом случае при одинаковой длине победит тот, кто запостил первым решение. Это ж немного спорт.

Answer (score 7):

Еще можно вот так извернуться (только C#). Можно сократить, но важна общая идея:

```
for (int i = min; ((Func<bool>)(() => { for (long j = min; j <= max; ++j) Console.WriteLine(j); return false; }))();)
```

Comment: Приз зрительских симпатий от меня :)

Answer (score 3):

В качестве новой идеи, ибо сильно длинно (38 символов):

```
for(int i=min;i<max;cout<<i++<<endl);int i=max;if(1)
    cout<<i<<endl;
```

UPD: В качестве развития последней идеи @Qwertiy (30 символов)

```
for(int i=min;0;);for(long i=min;i<=max;++i)
    cout<<i<<endl;
```

Comment: Неожиданно, да. :)

Comment: @VladD, надо было тело цикла длинным делать, чтоб его копипастить не хотелось. А так - да, красиво.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 34 символа

Для C# не подходит - нельзя объявлять одноимённые переменные во вложенных областях.

```
&0;!i++;)for(long i=min;i<=max;++i
```

http://ideone.com/Mdn48E

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename typed>
void print(typed min, typed max)
{
    if (min > max)
        throw 0;

    for (typed i = min&0;!i++;)for(long i=min;i<=max;++i)
        cout << i << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    print<signed char>(-3, 5);
    cout << '\n';
    print<signed char>(-128, -128);
    cout << '\n';
    print<signed char>(-128, 127);
    cout << '\n';
    print<signed char>(127, 127);
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) 

for (int i = min-1; i++ < max;) 

for (int i = min; min <= max; i = ++min)
```

Comment: Во втором варианте `min - 1` бросит исключение при `min = int.MinValue`

Comment: Да, точно, не учла

Comment: А в первом `i++` бросит исключение на последней итерации, если `max = int.MaxValue`.

Comment: Исправляйте :-)

Comment: @VladD, получилось только длиннее, но на этот раз вроде должно быть безопасно?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `++min` не переполняется?

Comment: @Ksenia Если б все было так просто, то армянское радио этим вопросом не занималось бы :)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>30</s> 26 символов

```
;i<=max;max&(i==max)?--max:++i   /* 30 символов */
;i<=max;i&i==max?--max:++i       /* 26 символов */
```

Работает если int.min чётный, а int.max - нечётный, что выполняется для встроенных целочисленных типов :)

http://ideone.com/F8FYHx
http://ideone.com/Yougv2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename typed>
void print(typed min, typed max)
{
  if (min > max)
    throw 0;

  for (typed i = min; i <= max; i&i==max ? --max : ++i)
    cout << (int)i << ' ';
}

int main()
{
  print<signed char>(-3, 5);
  cout << '\n';
  print<signed char>(-128, -128);
  cout << '\n';
  print<signed char>(-128, 127);
  cout << '\n';
  print<signed char>(127, 127);
  cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно сэкономить пару символов, если завести однобуквенный синоним для `max` (`for typed i = min, j = max;`).

Comment: А тут нет переполнения при вычитании --max?  Когда max = Int.Min ?

Comment: @pavel: когда `max = int.min` и `i = int.min`, то `i==max` даёт 1, `i&i==max` даёт `int.min & 1`, то есть, 0, т. к. `int.min` чётное. Поэтому в этом случае выполняется `++i`, а не `--max`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо) код сразу не совсем понятный в приоритете операций запутался)

Comment: @pavel: Ага, я в чате переспросил у автора :)

Comment: а теперь (лишь бы не практический) вопрос, что сделают с тем кто такое в прод закинет :)

Comment: @pavel: Любое гольфовое решение _очень_ не подходит для production. Се ля ви!

Answer (score -1):

Хм, а если, навскидку, такой вариант?

```
for (int i = min; i % max != 0; i++)
```

Comment: max = int.max => overflow.

Comment: И вообще, неверно же. `min=-1, max=10`.